# Moodle translation doesn't work

Tags: moodle

I'm trying to translate file in moodle>>languages. 
I changed english text for polish alternative text and it's not working , I already purged moodle cache , cache from browser and checked in database.mdl_tool_customlang . Everything looks ok but not working.

How to repair moodle to get languages from customlang sql database ?

Comment: I assume you clicked on 'save changes' when you finished? You might also want to look in [Moodle data]/lang/pl_local to see if your changes are saved there (assuming pl is the language code for Polish - I haven't checked).

Comment: lang is only en my friend

Comment: What's the default language for not authenticated users? Have you changed the language settings for your admin user?

Comment: I changed, all default are PL-pl

Comment: When you click on 'save changes' in the translation interface, the language files you have changed should be saved into your [Moodle data]/lang/pl_local (note that is your configured Moodle DATA directory, where uploaded files are stored, not the Moodle code directory).

If the files are not being written there, then that would explain the fact that the translation is not showing up. I suggest you make sure that debugging is on ( http://docs.moodle.org/en/Debugging ) and check for any error messages being displayed when you save your language pack modifications.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to install the Polish language pack first

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Language_packs

Then edit them via language customisation

http://docs.moodle.org/26/en/Language_customization

Comment: I did that ;) I'm changing words from Polish language pack , and not working

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the language customization tool (/admin/tool/customlang/index.php) to customize the translations? Because that's how it should be done. If you're changing it directly in the database or translation file (found in moodledata/lang/pl), it might not work correctly.

When using the customization tool, make sure you not only click on "Apply changes and continue editing" but also on "Save changes to the language pack".

One pitfall that I sometimes run into is editing the wrong text. Sometimes there are more than just one strings that contain the text to be edited and I'm changing the wrong one.

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to purge the moodle cache.

Most versions have a link at the bottom that will allow you to do this. If not, look at:

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Caching